# Looking for formulas/equations, by which I can replace $1.8\cdot 10^{19}$ numbers.

Tags: information-theory

I have a series of numbers between $281474976710655$ and $18446744073709552000$. I want to write one or more formulas/equations/etc. that can generate most of the numbers in the range.

For example, I can describe some of the numbers by Factorial, some by Fibonacci, some by power, etc. I'm looking for the most dominant and efficient formulas/equations that can replace all or most of these numbers.

Comment: good luck, doubt there is a general answer though.

Comment: Could you describe this series of numbers in more detail?

Comment: Previous versions of this question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3105785/generating-equations-values-for-each-number-between-0-and-4096 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3106640/writing-short-equations-equivalents-for-a-group-of-numbers

Comment: My answers to both of those don't seem to have helped, so maybe somebody else should try.

Comment: You can certainly describe them as strings of digits as you have.  Without some definition of what descriptions are acceptable there is no way to answer this or your other questions.  Most of the numbers will be "random", and not have any concise description.  You have completely missed the point that you can't compress numbers unless they come from some regular source.  If you have lots of numbers of this size, you need to store all the bits.  Again, unclear what you are asking.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing Short Equations/Equivalents For A Group Of Numbers.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3106640/writing-short-equations-equivalents-for-a-group-of-numbers)

Comment: @timtfj:  OP seems to have missed your points entirely.  He notes that some numbers have a compact representation and hopes that they all do, which is not correct.

Comment: @RossMillikan I know. The point is that the more compact the representation is, the fewer it works for, and the more information is needed to specify which format to use. Plus it adds redundancy so ends up being less efficient, not more efficient.

Comment: @timtfj:  I know that, but I suspect OP does not or is not willing to accept it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/89579/discussion-between-timtfj-and-ross-millikan).

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers. My numbers are between 281474976710655 and 18446744073709552000. The point is that I want to store a number of equations (it can even be 200) by which I can describe all of these numbers. The more compact the formula is, the better it would be. So far, I've been able to cover more than 10 million of these numbers in random by using Factorial, Fibonacci, and a few other formulas. Looking for any formulas and equations that can cover much more numbers than I have done so far.

Comment: Now you've got a few, I think you should work out the exact detail of how you'll store the formulas in the most compact way (down to the level of individual bits in the computer file) and calculate how much storage is needed overall, with and without the formulas. (For example, specify how the computer will know that $7$ doesn't mean $7!$, or how it will know how many bits are in each value.) This will tell you whether it's actually saving space or not.

Answer (score 0):

Still no formula suggestions I'm afraid, but I'd like to have one more try at explaining the problem with this approach to storing the numbers more compactly. (Previous attempt [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3106640/writing-short-equations-equivalents-for-a-group-of-numbers/3106838#3106838).)

I'll work through what happens with factorials, but I'll stick to small numbers to keep it manageable. You might like to try redoing the calculation for a different size of number, or a different "storage formula".

Let's just consider numbers which can be stored as a pair of characters: either two decimal digits, or one digit and the factorial sign. This means we're using $11$ symbols instead of $10$.

Using just digits, we can write the integers  from $0$ to $99$, i.e. $100$ different values.

Using one digit and the factorial sign, we can also represent $5!,6!,7!,8!$ and $9!$. (The lower factorials are below $100$ so already counted.) So we can represent $105$ different values altogether.

This is inefficient though, because some values have two representations and some combinations go unused. For example, $!6$ isn't used to represent anything, and $24$ is always stored as $4!$ instead.

But with $11$ different symbols, we *ought* to be able to represent $11^2=121$ different values, not just $105$.

So let's just use the extra symbol as an extra digit rather than as a factorial sign, and work in base $11$. Now we're able to represent $121$ different values using two characters.

If the numbers are being stored in a computer, this is still inefficient. Distinguishing $11$ different digits needs four bits to represent each one—but that's actually enough bits to distinguish $2^4=16$ different digits, We're wasting five of the possibilities for those bits.

So let's have $16$ different digits. We may as well call them $0123456789ABCDEF$. Now we're working in hexadecimal. Two digits will fit in one byte of memory, and can store any of $16^2=256$ different values. This is more than double the $105$ that we started with, and there's no waste at all. Every possible pair of digits represents a different number. Not only that, but the format is one that computers are set up to handle, **and** the numbers are all in the same format, making them easier to process.

Now, thinking about the short formulas. I'll admit that they do *look* like a more compact way of recording the information when written on paper. $7!$ is indeed shorter than $5040$ and $2^{16}$ is shorter than $65536$. If that was the whole story, they would save space. So how come they dont?

As humans, *we* know hundreds of different symbols when we see them, and instantly recognise the format. For us, adding $!$ or ^ to the available characters doesn't amount to writing down any additional information. We don't have to make  special arrangements to ensure that when we write a $2$, we could have written something else. The information is stored in the shape of the written symbol on the paper, with huge amounts of redundancy built in, and we can write pretty well anything. Any character from any language we know or don't know, any mathematical symbol, *anything* that our eyes can make out.

But in a computer it's different: each new symbol adds extra information to store. Maybe you now need to store each digit as an ASCII or Unicode character instead of as four bits, maybe most entries need marking to say "this one isn't a factorial", maybe you've got to insert a separator between entries because they're different lengths . . . And this extra information will **always** defeat any attempt to store $n$ bits' worth of information in less than $n$ bits.

If you find a formula that will work for all the numbers, it'll use at least as much storage as putting them all into hexadecimal would. If you find a format that's nice and short, it will only store a small subset of the numbers.

The most efficient approach is to find the most compact representation that will work *for every entry,* and use that.